# I get "website can't handle request" when trying to add form data into mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is my code:

```
<?php 

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pw", "dbname");

    //if( mysqli_connect_error()){ 

        //echo "There was an error"; 
    //}else{ 

        //echo "Database connection successful"; }

    // Check connection
    if ($link->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $link->connect_error);
    } 

//The problem started after I added the following code

    mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO posts (name, email, phonenumber, billAddress, billCity, billProvince, billPC)
    VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[phonenumber]', '$_POST[billAddress]', '$_POST[billCity]', '$_POST[billProvince]', '$_POST[billPC]')";



?>
```

Before adding the last bit of code, it was working fine.  After I added the code and hit refresh, I received http 500 error.  It also said my webpage isn't working and my webpage is currently unable to handle the request.

I am not sure if it is my coding problem or something else. Please help and thank you in advance.

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

Comment: Not your current problem but do realize you're allowing anyone to inject anything they want into your database queries. Please learn about parameters and never use this kind of code again. It might also show the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed out a closing bracket:

```
mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO posts (name, email, phonenumber, billAddress, billCity, billProvince, billPC))

VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[phonenumber]', '$_POST[billAddress]', '$_POST[billCity]', '$_POST[billProvince]', '$_POST[billPC]')";
```

---

Also, remember to escape the string using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to prevent MySQL Injection.

---

**Tip:** You should turn on [**Error Reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) by adding this code to the top of your PHP files which will assist you in finding errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: @Hsk3502 Does this solve your problem? Maybe accept it by clicking the tick mark under the upvote/ downvote buttons, thanks!

Comment: I have added the missing bracket and it still says the webpage can't handle the request.  I'm also aware the current code is open to injections and looking to learn more about it.  I have even tried rewriting everything using just the most basic code and still it says my website can't handle the request.